# Wordpress redirected automatically to other site

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress website was redirecting to other site. It was hacked. I just delete the folder cache in wp-content folder. And it resolved.

Can u tell me where was exact problem?

Comment: It will be back again if you didn't clan the malware. You can scan with WordFence plugin.

Comment: Thank you for fast response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your admin password or it will be back again, look into log files, I'm pretty sure that "someone" pass through your admin to update file in editor.

You can also go to ***wp-config.php*** and add : `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true );`